# Debugging multicast connection over VPN

Tags: vpn, openvpn, multicast

I'm running Ubuntu 11.10. I have a local application that is trying to receive multicast UDP streams via an OpenVPN tunnel. I have network connectivity to the remote host that is generating the multicast data and can access that host properly. In addition, if I fire up Wireshark on my local machine, it is able to see the UDP packets coming through with the designated multicast destination addresses. However, my client application isn't indicating that it has received any data, so I'm trying to figure out the reason why.

Is there a simple tool that I can use at the command line to verify that the multicast traffic is being passed through to the user level? I'm wondering if there is something between Wireshark and userland that is filtering the packets for some reason. I've also tried using `tcpdump` as follows:

```
sudo tcpdump -n -i tap0 -s 1536 udp
```

When I run this command, I also see messages fly by showing reception of the packets as I would expect. I'm not too familiar with the innards of `tcpdump`, however; I'm not sure if it's also peeking down further under the hood than a typical user application would. Any suggestions?

Comment: use `ip maddr` to check you've actually assigned the multicast address to the machine.

Comment: I tried doing a `ip maddr add 224.0.1.1 dev tap0`, and the command seems to execute successfully, but when I subsequently do a `ip maddr show`, the multicast address isn't shown under `tap0`.